# Add different result to one of the options of a select box

Tags: jquery, function, drop-down-menu, calculator

I’ve got a simple calculator that takes data from two select boxes and calculate it. 
But I need an extra feature for that calculator, so for example when I choose the the third option in the first select box, the calculator just gives me the particular text instead of calculation.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<select>
<option value=“">Days</option>
<option data-price=“30” value=‘1'>1</option>
<option data-price=“40” value=‘2'>2 </option>
<option data-price=“50" value='3'>**3**</option>
</select>


<select>
<option value=“">People</option>
<option data-price=“10" value='1'>1 </option>
<option data-price="15" value='2'>2 </option>
<option data-price=“20" value='2'>3 </option>
</select>
```

JS

```
var $selects = $("select").change(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $selects.each(function () {
        var price = parseFloat($(this).find("option:selected").data("price")) || 0;
        total += price;
    })
    $(".count h2").text('€ ' + total);
})
```

[image]

Comment: plz provide some more explanation what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vuc4n3y2/)

```
$("select").on('change',function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('select').each(function () {
        var price = parseFloat($(this).find("option:selected").data("price")) || 0;
        total += price;
    })
    if($('select:eq(0)').find("option:selected").index() == 3){
        text = $('select:eq(0)').find("option:selected").text() ;
        $(".count h2").text(text);
    } else {
        $(".count h2").text('€ ' + total);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've got.  It seems that it works.

```
$("select").on('change',function () {
var total = 0;
$('select').each(function () {
    var price = parseFloat($(this).find("option:selected").data("price")) || 0;
    total += price;
})
if($('select:eq(0)').find("option:selected").index() == 3){
    text = $('select:eq(0)').find("option:selected").val() ;
    $(".count h2").text(text);
} else {
    $(".count h2").text('€ ' + total);
}
```

})